# consulta elocuent leftjoin en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

cuando estoy desarrollando mis consultas para mis controladores acostumbro primero practicarlas en SQL para luego pasarlas a eloquent y se facilite su lógica. en este momento tengo una consulta SQL que quiero pasar a eloquent pero tengo unos problemas, no se como anidar un join dentro de otro join, en SQL si me da el resultado que busco pero en eloquent no lo e podido hacer

la consulta trata que:
consulta los todos los estados y tráeme los tickets que su servicio pertenezcan a un tipo de servicio.

```
select cat_estados_ticket.nombre_estado,
COUNT( tickets.id_solicitud_ticket) AS cuantos
from cat_estados_ticket
left join(
  select tickets.id_solicitud_ticket,
  tickets.id_estado_ticket,
  servicios.id_clase_servicio
  from tickets
  inner join servicios ON tickets.id_servicio = servicios.id_servicio
  where servicios.id_area_servicio=1    
) AS tickets ON cat_estados_ticket.id_estado_ticket = tickets.id_estado_ticket
group by cat_estados_ticket.id_estado_ticket,cat_estados_ticket.nombre_estado
order by cat_estados_ticket.id_estado_ticket
```

[image: resultado de la consulta SQL y el que espero en eloquent]

Comment: Hay algunos ejemplos en la documentación de cómo anidar un join en otro,  dale una mirada y agrega a la pregunta lo que has intentado https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins

Comment: gracias ya leí, lo que me marcaste si me funciono